# How do I code or refer to my user ID from rails console in my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to refer to my user id in a bit of code to modify the view on my `index.html.erb` WITHOUT success.

In the rails console of my project I am User with id: 1,

How should my user id be called exactly please in the syntax.

Right now I have..

> Index.html.erb

```
<% if current_user == "#User id:1" %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(pin) %>
  <%= link_to 'Destroy', pin, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can compare ids, you can write

```
<% if current_user.id == your_id %>
```

for example.

I recommend you add a `owner` or `admin` boolean field in your `User` model, in that case your code will look like:

```
<% if current_user.admin %>
```

Or you can define `my_user` method as helper, that will return your user instance and compare it with your `current_user`:

```
<% if current_user == my_user %>
```

in `application_helper.rb`:

```
def my_user
  User.find(1)
end
```

It is a dirty way, but it will works.

Comment: <% if current_user.id == User_id 1 %>

Comment: like this or with a colon, can you be specific please

Comment: why are you sending my answer for review, I'm no wanting to go through the model

Comment: I am not looking to code in the admin, please refer to my question. user id 1

Comment: i edited my answer. You can write `if current_user.id == 1` of course, if you want. But what happened, if you delete your user and create a new? You will rewrite a lot of code in this case. It is a bad way.

Comment: really appreciate your time and that worked. I understand your methadology of going through the model with a proper admin set up in active records, will upvote in a minute

Comment: Your answer works without inputting the code in the application_helper.rb As a new coder, what is the benefit of using this further code

Comment: if you inputting method in `application_helper.rb`, you can use this method in views

Comment: Hmmm, its already in my index page in views without it.... strange and it works in development mode